# Storing variables of Android Views (button, TextViews etc.)

Tags: android, variables, android-layout, view

I currently have an application that is storing around 10 variables per android view in which all of the views need to have their variables changed dynamically. How would be the best way of storing these variables in an efficient way and or would be less code because as of right now I have around 200 variables and each one being called like 4 times to change the variables.

So like this:

`String buttonName = "blah";`

`buttonName = newValue;`

Would using an ArrayList save more code and help OOD? Also most of the views have ints, floats, & String variables assigned to them. I need a good way to save code that could possibly work for multiple Views that all need different values. Any Ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extend whatever Views you are using and store the additional variables in your extended class...

```
 //constructor
 public class MyButton extends Button{
   public String someVariable;
   public Button(Context c){
       super(c);
   }

 }
```

then in your code you would use it like...

```
MyButton b = new MyButton(this);
b.someVariable = "foofy";
```

Comment: would this allow for more than one button view to be changed etc.?
not all at once but storing different variables for different views? 
Or will I need a new class for each button view?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're doing, so, it's hard to answer your question. But your extended class can have as many members are you see fit to give it, and of course you can create as many instances of this  object as you want.  What other kinds of views are you using? Images? TextView?  I have to say that at first glance I get the sense that you're doing something "not quite right" but it's hard to say given your relatively vague description.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness its just hard to explain the app basically adds random android views to a layout and allows the user to dynamically change the views on the go. which extends to most of the android views.

Comment: ah your method worked having issues when more than one button is created but a very helpful step in the right direction. Thank you Dr. Dredel

Comment: happy to help. If you lay out some more details of what you're doing, I may be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: Well what I would like to do is now seeing your example possibly use what you said but instead of having button1Text = "Blah", Button2Text = "Blah", button3Text = "Blah"...ect... I'd like to just have one variable buttonText within a class that could act as a universal variable for all button views tho where it gets difficult is I would like each button to be able to say something different. So instead of having 20 different String variables for 20 different Button Views I could have one String variable for all Button Views.

Comment: going off your example if I create a new MyButton instant for each Button I should be able to have one String variable for multiple buttons correct?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand completely what you mean. But I'll give it a go.

If I were you I'd create myself a "Holder" class that contains all the variables that you need to store contained in it. Then once you instantiate an Object of that class and populate the values you can "attach" it to a particular view using the `view.setTag(Object);` method. Whenever you need to retrieve them you can find a reference to your holder object with `(YourHolderClass)view.getTag();` Note that getTag will return a plain object, you must cast it. The tag object will stick with this view the whole time it is around so you are always able to retrieve it

edit: [View.setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to change these variables and then have their new values displayed in the UI? If so you can simply have a method for setting the display values in the UI. You could call this during onCreate or onResume, and then again anytime some values have changed. You could also use encapsulate with a custom View and then call invalidate so that it gets redrawn.

Comment: yes once the views variables have changed I have the layout refresh which isn't the issue I'm necessarily having. I don't want to seem rude or not grateful, thank you so much for the help. I'm looking for a way to move my variables out of the main activity class file and maybe find a way to store them in a data structure per view or something. Something that would save time and code, rather than having everything in one file. I'm kinda having trouble expressing it in a way I apologize.

Comment: it would be helpful to know what these variables actually are.  Can you provide an example of what you're storing in them and how you intend to use this data?